# Line over multiple rows

Tags: line

[image]

Does anyone know, how to create something like this? I think it could work with tables, but I do not know if the lines will align that perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version using `arydshln`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llllll}
A: & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{1} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
B: & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{1} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\cdashline{4-4}
C: & 1 & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{0} & 0 & 1 \\
\cdashline{4-4}
D: & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{0} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\cdashline{4-4}
E: & 1 & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{1} & 0 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\setlength{\dashlinedash}{2pt}
\setlength{\dashlinegap}{0.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
A: & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{1} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
B: & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{1} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\cdashline{4-4}
C: & 1 & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{0} & 0 & 1 \\
\cdashline{4-4}
D: & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{0} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\cdashline{4-4}
E: & 1 & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{1} & 0 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\setlength{\dashlinedash}{1pt}
\setlength{\dashlinegap}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
A: & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{1} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
B: & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{1} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\cdashline{4-4}
C: & 1 & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{0} & 0 & 1 \\
\cdashline{4-4}
D: & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{0} & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\cdashline{4-4}
E: & 1 & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{l:}{1} & 0 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

One option is using a `NiceTabular` from  the `nicematrix` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lccccc}
A: & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
B: & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
C: & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
D: & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
E: & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [dashed] (1-|4) -- ([yshift=0.2ex]3-|4) -| ([yshift=0.2ex]4-|5) -| (6-|4);
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]